# Calculate billable hours and exceeded hours as null

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created a sample Excel (https://snakeware-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/marco_snakeware_nl/Efw_66O6M8FBoPueVjFV3m0BEDkApYcTN-W_6NY4PwrE3Q?e=tIUBfQ) with hours and projects. 
The projects have budgets and the HOURS is what is reported by our employees.

I am trying to created a report where you can see by week, by team, how much money they "earned". i use the following formula to do this.

```
=SUMIFS(HOURS!$U:$U;HOURS!$E:$E;C3;HOURS!$F:$F;$B$4)
```

It gives me the SUM of hours, per team, per week, so it does what is should. 
There is one thing missing. If there is a budget on a project, for example on project 4 there is a budget of €19.920 in week 1 i am still within budget, so no problem. From week 21 and further, the budget is completely used and thus i can't count the amount of hours anymore in my weekreport. What should the formula look like when i want to exclude the "over budget" hours?

**Expected result:** 
Week 23 for "Team T", should show €5040,-
while it now shows €10080,-

Comment: You might be better dropping into VBA and writing a function

Comment: we dont have privileges do see your link

Comment: totally unclear what you are asking